# Scrolling to and vertically centering an element inside a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to scroll to an element inside a div, and center it vertically in the div.

I have tried so far this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/gus2LhfL/) but no luck.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#scroll_button', function(e) {
    var el = $( "#scroll_test" );
    var elOffset = el.offset().top;
    var elHeight = el.height();
    var windowHeight = $("#editor").height();
    var offset;

    if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
        offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
    }
    else {
        offset = elOffset;
    }

    jQuery('#editor').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scroll_test").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

I am using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150090/jquery-scroll-element-to-the-middle-of-the-screen-instead-of-to-the-top-with-a), but it is not working as per the fiddle. The scroll gets where the element is at the top of the holding element. I would like to have it in the vertical center.

I also learned that using jQuery to get an element's height maybe inaccurate, and pure js should be used, but I did not have luck with that [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435604/getting-an-elements-inner-height).

I started from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element) question originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#editor').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 1000);
});
```

You forgot to use your conditional `offset` value.

Comment: Yes, @gnCupo beat me to it. Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maneeshchiba/13jex6p5/1/)