# when i am Trying to scroll the page using anchor and id, its not working fine

Tags: javascript, html

When i am clinking on that **Check out Here !** button
its not coming perfectly in middle of screen

here is the link for http://wineoir.com/index.html?

i want to align that video part in middle of screen
pls help me ! how to do that

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="img/branding-2.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="tv">

            <p> &nbsp;</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 ">
            <p> &nbsp; </p>
            <p> &nbsp;</p>
            <p> &nbsp; </p>
            <p> &nbsp; </p>
            <h2 class="text-center">Now aerate and pour your wine with a button's push<br> Electronic Wine Aerator</h2>
            <p class="text-center"><a href="#video" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Check out Here ! </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="img/bigimage2.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="tv">
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p> &nbsp; </p>
            <p> &nbsp;</p>
            <p> &nbsp; </p>
            <h2 class="text-center">Mixes Wine and Air to provide a optimum Wine flavour and mouthfeel Video</h2>

        </div>
        <p class=""></p>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="video" class="vid">
                <iframe width="450" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e0mM42ZduTQ" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
            </div>   <!-- vid -->

        </div>
        <!--.col -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21778615/4108884 -> with a little rework for your elements, this will do desired effect.

Comment: yes you are correct @SamuilPetrov

Answer (score 0):

if your page will be like this, you can navigate at the bottom of the page with this, and your video will be at the center: at the `id='anchor'` to your `a` element

```
 $("#anchor").click(function() {
      $("#video").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");

    });​
```

Comment: This is not a quality solution, if today the page is "like this", tomorrow it may not. P.S: Also this won't work for some device sizes in the current case.

Answer (score 0):

The feeling that it does scroll a bit too low in the page comes from the height of the navbar. I would simply pick an element before the `<hr />` tag as an anchor. (Your `<p>`-tags would come in handy here, but please don't use `<p>`-tags as spacers, make yourself a CSS class to achieve the desired space effect and then put your anchor tag on a `<div>` with that class)

Answer (score 0):

Placing the id="anchor" on another element higher up on the page is not a very clean solution. On your live site, when I click "Check out here", the placement of the video is still not "centered" (although I can still see your video).

Ultimately, if you are concerned with such aesthetics, relying on anchor placement will never be good.

Other strategies:

1 - Find a website theme which provides better layout aesthetics. Usually such themes will use a combination of responsive CSS and Javascript to spread content out, center things nicely and even animate things nicely. You will find a lot of "One page" themes have these kinds of traits. [Here's an example](https://www.inkthemes.com/previews/?demo_id=482). Traditional HTML anchor links are more geared toward easily navigating giant text documents.

2 - Investigate placing your videos in modals which appear gracefully  over top of your entire page, with the page dimmed in the background. Like [this tutorial](http://azmind.com/bootstrap-tutorial-modal-video/).

Comment: Thanks a lot man,2nd option looking beautiful and working ulitmately,,, @MarsAndBack