# can smooth scroll to a component cause other components to blur in jquery/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm using the solution proposed here [jQuery scrollTo - Center Div in Window Vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889983/jquery-scrollto-center-div-in-window-vertically) and it works, when I hit some link on my webpage, I immediately see smooth scrolling that stops when my  header is in the middle of the screen. However, I have several other components above and below, so I thought about bluring them until the user scrolls up or down - is that even possible in jquery or css?

I prepared small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea67uqd6/1/) with the code so far, I just have trouble with attaching jquery library itself, so the smooth scroll might now be visible there... But all in all I'm using the following script:

```
$('#borders a').on('click', function(e) { 
  var el = $( e.target.getAttribute('href') );
  var elOffset = el.offset().top;
  var elHeight = el.height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var offset;

  if (elHeight < windowHeight) {
    offset = elOffset - ((windowHeight / 2) - (elHeight / 2));
  }
  else {
    offset = elOffset;
  }

  $.smoothScroll({ speed: 700 }, offset);
  return false;
});
```

EDIT:: I marked this quesion as solved since the correct answer was given below, however it appeard to me later on that it doesn't work in my case. That's why I've decided to ask another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678607/blurring-other-components-in-javascript-and-css-does-not-work-after-scrolling)

Comment: I just saw your jsFiddle - you were put Javascript code in CSS panle !!. it should place it in Jvascript Code Panle.

Comment: There's the CSS blur filter, but not supported by IE (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). You could try using a semi-transparent PNG as a foreground to "blurred" elements. As for applying the efect itself a CSS class on those elements should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can use SmoothScroll’s beforeScroll event to blur all elements except the one you’re scrolling to.

```
$.smoothScroll({
    afterScroll: function() {
        $('.el').not(target).animate({ opacity: 0.25 });
    }
});
```

Then, remove opacity when you’re scrolling.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.el').animate({ opacity: 1 });
});
```

To prevent animations being triggered on every scroll, check out [the edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea67uqd6/3/).

Instead of applying CSS directly, you can use add and remove classes to keep styling exclusively in your CSS files.

https://jsfiddle.net/ea67uqd6/4/

Comment: I've tried to test your solution on my case and it unfortunately didn't work... I've created a new question for it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678607/blurring-other-components-in-javascript-and-css-does-not-work-after-scrolling Could you step by for a while and help me with that issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a very simple `filter` property in CSS3 you can apply to all other elements if you wish to do so.

```
filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
```

Do note this is not supported in IE. IE *had* an older property that worked up to IE8, but it doesn't work from IE9+

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='5');
```

Answer (score -2):

I tried below Demo:
[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/hegksphh/1/)

### Using JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```